# Pass Dynamic Parameter from JavaScript to PHP via AJAX for Use in cURL Call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, php-curl

I am using php curl to make a http get long polling request from my javascript using Ajax. Here is the call from javascript

```
var i;
i++;
$.ajax({
   url:"http://localhost/myport.php",
   type: GET,
   success: function(response){ ...},
   ...
   ...
```

Here is how I make the php call in the myport.php file

```
 <?php
 $ch=curl_init();
 $curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:7555/test?index=" //Here I need to set a value (the variable i) in the above JS
```

If I making the call directly from js, I would do

```
$.ajax({ url:"http://localhost:7555/test?index=" + i
```

I am new to php and curl, I am wondering how I can pass the value of that variable so I can get a parameter for the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and you just want to append the value of the variable `$i` to the cURL call, you'd do this:

```
<?php
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:7555/test?index=" . $i);
```

Or even,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, sprintf("http://localhost:7555/test?index=%d", $i));
```

Also note hat there is no `$` before a function call: it's `curl_setopt()` not `$curl_setopt()` (`$` is for variables, like `$ch`).

**Edit**

Upon clarification of the question, it seems you need to get this `i` variable from JavaScript to PHP. You can pass it as a `GET` parameter in your AJAX call:

```
var i;
i++;
$.ajax({
   url:"http://localhost/myport.php?index=" + i,
   type: GET,
   success: function(response){ ...},
   ...
   ...
```

Then, from PHP, you can use it like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, sprintf("http://localhost:7555/test?index=%d", $_GET['index']));
```

You should also verify that `$_GET['index']` was actually passed in:

```
if (!isset($_GET['index']))
{
    die("The index was not specified!");
}
```

Comment: I am sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to get the parameters for the curl call from Javascript. How can I do that? As I showed, the ajax is calling the php which then calls the http get request.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `i` from JavaScript like in your last example, with `?index=`, then read the value of `index` in php from the global variable `$_GET["index"]`.